# How to Add JS Interface on Crosswalk Shared Mode

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk-runtime

I have a problem on adding JS interface to XWalkView in Shared Mode.
Everything is easy when using embbeded XwalkView, we can add JS interface directly to XWalkView, but in Shared Mode, how does it should be done?

Basicly, how to get the XwalkView object while the app on activity that extended from XWalkRuntimeActivityBase.